# asp.net website SQL connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web

i'm having problems getting my ASP.NET site to log me in using SQL, here is some code (Login.ASPX.CS);

```
        private bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        if (this.IsAlphaNumeric(userName) && userName.Length <= 50 && password.Length <= 50)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                string sql = "select count(*) from dbo.Users where UserName = '@username' and password = '@password'";

                conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MembershipSiteConStr"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                SqlParameter user = new SqlParameter();
                user.ParameterName = "@username";
                user.Value = userName.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(user);

                SqlParameter pass = new SqlParameter();
                pass.ParameterName = "@password";
                pass.Value = Hasher.HashString(password.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pass);

                conn.Open();

                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count > 0) returnValue = true;
            }
```

Here is my web.config connectionstring

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="MembershipSiteConStr" connectionString="Data Source=dev-pc\;Initial Catalog=MembershipSite;User ID=test;Password=test" />
```

i've tested this SQL connection using server explorer and SQL managment and it all works.

here are some SP of what's going on;

[image]

here is evidence that the user and pass im putting in should work;
 The user is there:

[image]

that the SQL query works:

[image]

Comment: Try removing "\" after `Data Source`

Comment: What behaviour are you getting back? Do you know if your code is going into the catch handler for an exception (in your try-catch block)? If it does, have a look at the exception details.

Comment: If you could post the exception you get, it could help us giving you a better advice. If you do not get any exceptions, try to single-step (F11 in visual studio) your application to find out which lines actually gets executed. As Marius mentioned - it is interresting to know if the try-catch block is being executed. It is also relevant to know if it succedes to establish a connection. You could examine the conn variable after the program have passed the line starting with: "conn = new SqlConnection(..."

Comment: i've not used this function before but after running it i'm not getting any errors / warnings

Comment: @shaharyar i've tried this and still not allowing me to log in

Comment: Instead of `connectionString="Data Source=dev-pc\` this put IP address of Your server `connectionString="Data Source=192.xx.xx.xx`

Comment: @jaydip-jadhav i've tried the following I.P address 127.0.0.1 / 192.168.0.9 (static) and external I.P address, still not allowing me to log in =[

Comment: ok what exception is occure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code of Adding Password Parameter as follow

```
 SqlParameter pass = new SqlParameter();
 pass.ParameterName = "@password";
 //pass.Value = Hasher.HashString(password.Trim());
 pass.Value = password.Trim(); 
 cmd.Parameters.Add(pass);
```

Comment: well done that was it :o seems my hasher is wrong somewhere, Great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the provider name at connectionStrings

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="MembershipSiteConStr" connectionString="Data Source=dev-pc\;Initial Catalog=MembershipSite;User ID=test;Password=test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Okay, i've tested this and still not allowing me to login.